# Java applet networking

Tags: java, sockets, networking, applet, client-server

I am looking into java networking and want to be more knowledgeable and learn this subject of java, and to do so I decided I would make a simple online chat type applet so that it can interface between the clients.

The applet part of it is fine, and I understand how to do that, but I am not sure where to begin looking, or specifically what to be looking at, for the networking part. I have my own webserver and want to be able to use that as the actual server part, and I'm not sure if the tutorials I have looked at is what I need to be looking at.

Basically, I just want Client -> Server <- Client so that all of the clients can see the same message, so not sure where to start.

These were the main pages I was referencing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Have a look [at this applet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/clientExample.html). Note that with Java applets you can only communicate with the server from which the applet was served. This is for security reasons.

Comment: Yeah that was another one that I had looked at before, but would that type of setup work on a webserver?

Comment: It provides a server, that starts a thread and listens for messages. Another thing to consider is using HTTP (HttpURLConnection) to communicate with the server.

Comment: So could I use the server that is provided on an actual website/server?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the easiest.

Comment: *"Java applets .. can only communicate with the server from which the applet was served."*  Not entirely true.  If the applet is digitally signed by the developer, and trusted when prompted by the end user, it can communicate with any server that will accept connections from it.  But for this use-case, I as end user would want to see a sand-boxed applet.

Comment: @Andrew, yes you are right, though as a practical matter we probably agree that you generally don't want to do that.

Comment: @FrancisUpton  I tend to prefer sand-boxed apps. wherever possible.  With the services of the [JNLP API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html), that becomes 'a lot of the time'.  This was a problem for applets embedded in pre plug-in 2 JREs (for which the JNLP API was unavailable), but it has always been available to free floating applets and apps. launched using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 3):

A Socket is - IP Address + Port Number.

(Think of a port numbers as many doors to same room so that many people can get into it at a same time).

Now, a chat server's job is to listen to all the requests coming through TCP on that port number of the machine. It is a infinite loop like: `while(true) { listen to port number xxxx }`. Now a chat client function is to establish a connecion to the server at that IP Address on that port number (eg. 127.0.0.1:2020). Now after connection is established you can send data to the server.

(In case of chat server when the server recieves message from one client, it broadcasts the message to all the clients).

java.net package provides ServerSocket and Socket class to perform these tasks.

Commonly used objects in java.net are-

MalformURLException, BindException, ConnectException, UnknownHOstException, SocketTimeoutException, PortUnreachableException,
URL, URI, URLStreamHandler,
Inet4Address,
MulticastSocket, ServerSocket, Socket, URLEncoder, URLDecoder.

The GUI part you can make it yourself as you said you are good in applet ( I am bad in applet).

Comment: So basically, if I understand you correctly, the server would be just a normal .java file which would listen to all of the incoming requests. Then the client would be the one with the GUI(of course) and they would try to establish a connection with the server,(the following is where I am stuck at) once established they would send a message to the server and the server would add it to each connections display?

Answer (score 2):

you can visit [this](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html) tutorial. It will show step by step building chat application in java,

first without GUI, and end up with a basic chat application with GUI. All the best :)
.

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising